# Ideas on getting average max on historic data transactions

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I do hope this kind of question is OK. I do not know what to search for here on SO or Google etc. to find possible solutions.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.

I've got loads of data with parking ticket transactions from various parking meters.
All records contain a timestamp_begin, timestamp_end and parking_meter_id cell.

If I want to see the currently active tickets for a parking meter I just count tickets where NOW() is between timestamp_begin and timestamp_end and group by parking_id.

But what if I would like to know if the currently active tickets is higher or lower than some sort of average max from historical data, such as the last month?

I would like to be able to show if it's perhaps possible to find a free parking spot near a certain parking meter, based on it's activity compared to historical data.

How should I approach such a challenge? I'm lost for ideas...

Comment: Please edit your question so it includes sample data and the results that you would like to see.

Comment: Your post contains at least two very different questions (finding average and finding free parking spots). Please delete one question (you can always post another one).

Comment: Questions like this are a *lot* easier if you provide some sample data - preferably as a http://sqlfiddle.com/ - so we can test things. From the vague description provided, I think you *might* want to use `avg`, `sum` and/or `count` as window functions to get a rolling or partitioned aggregate, but it's really hard to be sure when you don't show sample data and expected results.

Comment: I'm sorry for the vague question, I actually thought it as one question. The question about a free parking spot near a parking meter was to explain the use for my project. My idea was to use historical data to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case` to easily compare current and previous month. (Note that `Now()` works right now on my computer, but you may have different time and get different results).

```
-- drop table if exists parking;

create table parking
  (timestamp_begin timestamp, 
   timestamp_end timestamp,
   parking_meter_id integer);

insert into parking values
  ('2014-05-25 12:01','2014-05-25 13:00',1),
  ('2014-05-25 12:02','2014-05-25 14:00',1), 
  ('2014-05-25 12:03','2014-05-25 15:00',2),
  ('2014-05-25 12:04','2014-05-25 16:00',2),
  ('2014-06-25 12:30','2014-06-25 16:00',1),
  ('2014-06-25 12:31','2014-06-25 16:00',1), 
  ('2014-06-25 12:32','2014-06-25 16:00',2),
  ('2014-06-25 12:30','2014-06-25 16:00',2),
  ('2014-06-25 12:34','2014-06-25 16:00',3),
  ('2014-06-25 12:30','2014-06-25 16:00',3);

select
  parking_meter_id,
  sum(case when Now() between timestamp_begin and timestamp_end 
           then 1 else 0 end) as current_data,
  sum(case when Now() - interval '1 month' between timestamp_begin and timestamp_end 
           then 1 else 0 end) as prev_month_data
from
  parking  
group by
  parking_meter_id
order by
  parking_meter_id
;
```

Results

```
parking_meter_id current_data prev_month_data
1 2 0
2 2 2
3 2 0
```

Comment: This look very interesting and thank you for the provided SQL-query, I will have a look at it, it does look quite as what I'm searching for.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just answer question 1: how to get an avarage to compare with. I'm with Tomas Greif; you should make that "free parking spot near a certain parking meter" a separate request.

First: Make a good rule what to compare with. Parking will be different on a Saturday, a Sunday or a Monday. So you may want to compare just with the same weekday and time. (Still one day may have been a holiday, so this method still isn't great). Let's say we want to look back three months. First get the number of active tickets for each day we consider appropriate for comparision, then get the avarage over all these days.

```
select avg(cnt) -- avarage number of active tickets on the compared days
from
(
  select count(*) as cnt -- number of active tickets per day (as we group by day)
  from tickets
  where parking_id = 100
  and timestamp_begin >= now() - interval '3 month' -- last three months
  and to_char(timestamp_begin,'YYYYMMDD') < to_char(now(),'YYYYMMDD') -- but not today
  and to_char(timestamp_begin,'D') = to_char(now(),'D') -- same weekday
  and to_char(now(),'HH24MISS') between to_char(timestamp_begin,'HH24MISS') and to_char(timestamp_end,'HH24MISS') -- same time
  group by to_char(timestamp_begin,'YYYYMMDD') -- group by day
) other_days;
```

There may be typos or even small errors in the concept, but you get the idea.

Comment: I agree, there is a lot of issues to take into account, such as holidays etc. Thank you for the example, I will have a look at it.